# Javascript onclick event on newly created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I've got several functions all linked so it will ...

1. create new elements and set their properties and stuff
2. once elements are in place they should trigger function.

And they do! Kind of...

More like they trigger half of a function that's attached to them upon creation. The part where they onclick trigger a function that starts a loading on my progress bar (which is their purpose) is alright. But the much simpler part, where they hide after click, doesn't.

As the code is quite complex I'll place here larger part of it, so don't panic. Problem might be somewhere else then I expect. Here it is...

```
// defines function for checkpoint
    function checkpointed() {   
                this.style.display = 'none'; // !here dwells the douch part!
                if (toLoad < 100) {
                    toLoad += 100/$(this).attr('numButs');
                    var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50);
            }

    // defining creation of checkpoints
    function checkpoints(num) { 
        var angle = 4.72,
        step = (2 * Math.PI) / num;
        for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
            var x = $('#progressBar').width()/2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) ; 
            var y = $('#progressBar').height()/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle);
            angle += step;
            var newContent = document.createElement('IMG');
            var newCheckpoint = document.createElement('SPAN');
            var numButs = document.createAttribute('numButs');
            numButs.value = num;
            var Class = document.createAttribute('class');
            Class.value = 'checkpoint';
            var img = document.createAttribute('src');
            img.value = 'img/lock.png';
            newContent.setAttributeNode(img);
            newCheckpoint.setAttributeNode(numButs);
            newCheckpoint.setAttributeNode(Class);
            $(newCheckpoint).append(newContent);
            $('.projectBar').append(newCheckpoint);
            x -= 24;
            y -= 24;
            $(newCheckpoint).offset({top:y, left: x});
            newCheckpoint.onclick = checkpointed;
        };
    };

    // creates checkpoints upon clicking on create button
    document.getElementById('create').onclick = function(){ 
        checkpoints(document.getElementById('numCheckpoint').value);
        $(this).hide();
        $('#numCheckpoint').hide();
    };
```

I should probably sum up what is this all about.

I have circular progressBar that measures progression of users project. User says "Hey, my project has like 5 steps (or 20 idc)" and "create" button will make 5 checkpoints placed on the progressBar evenly. By clicking on checkpoints you load the progress bar by 20% per clicked checkpoint.

Don't worry though, I've already figured out the code for loading and the geometrics.

However I'm bit stuck here... on simple onclick functions. Please if you have an idea try achieve it with plain JavaScript or jQuery (trying to do this without other frameworks, libraries or plugins).

EDIT: Just found out that checkpoint are set alright, as they really hide after clicking. Problem is in creation of checkpoints as the loop creates about 15 more checkpoints stacked one on another. So you have to click each of them to hide them all... So problem is in the loop.

EDIT2: Figured it out. The loop `for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)` had the `num`parameter as a String coming from input field. So simple `parseInt()` did the trick.

Comment: Quick question: if you're already using jQuery, why are you making your life so much harder with all the `document.createElement, document.createAttribute` stuff? `var newCheckpoint = $("<span class='checkpoint'></span>).append("<img src='img/lock.png'"></img>")` is rather easier.

Comment: Any error in console? Not related, but why do you mix jQuery with plain javascript DOM access?

Comment: @KevinB My mistake, then.

Comment: @albert-nemec: can you clarify what the problem is? It seems like it's just that something doesn't hide, but since you seem to only mention this in passing in paragraph 4, it's not totally clear whether there are other issues. If that's the only issue, another question: Does `$('#numCheckpoint').hide();` work in the console? Why or why not?

Comment: @SamFen That is actually good question. I do it to learn working with plain javascript, however truth is that the combination of jQuery and JS is probably not the best habit, I agree.

Console is without errors. When I check via console.log wheter element is hidden it says it is. Which is why I don't understand why it's still on screen. 

$('#numCheckpoint').hide(); works in console, but also doesn't actually hide element. 

I just found out that when I click ".checkpoint" for like a 15 times, It does hide.

Comment: `$('#numCheckpoint').hide(); works in console, but also doesn't actually hide element.` This statement doesn't make sense to me. In what sense does it "work" then? How about another test: Just type in `$('#numCheckpoint')` in the console. You should get an array back. In Chrome, at least, when you hover over one of the returned elements of that array, the correct element should highlight in blue in the document. Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mixed Jquery and plain Javascript is messing with my head... Any way how about when you create a new element, give it some sort of class. Instead of giving setting onclick, use jQuery's on selector to bind click events to those dynamic elements. Try The Following:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".Checkpoint", function(event) {
    $(event.target).hide();
    if (toLoad < 100) {
      toLoad += 100 / $(this).attr('numButs');
      var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50);
    }
  });

  // defining creation of checkpoints
  function checkpoints(num) {
    var angle = 4.72,
      step = (2 * Math.PI) / num;
    for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
      var x = $('#progressBar').width() / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle);
      var y = $('#progressBar').height() / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle);
      angle += step;
      var newContent = $('<img></img>');
      var newCheckpoint = $('<span></span>');
      $("body").append(newCheckpoint);
      newContent.attr("numButs", num);
      newContent.attr("src", 'img/lock.png');
      newContent.addClass("Checkpoint");

      $(newCheckpoint).append(newContent);
      $('.projectBar').append(newCheckpoint);
      x -= 24;
      y -= 24;
      $(newCheckpoint).offset({
        top: y,
        left: x
      });

    }
  }

  // creates checkpoints upon clicking on create button
  $(document).on("click","#create",function(e) {
    checkpoints($('#numCheckpoint').val());
    $(e.target).hide();
    $('#numCheckpoint').hide();
  });
```

Changed stuff to work more in jQuery, hope you don't mind...

Comment: Well this might be somehow relevant. Although when I use your code, creation of checkpoints gets really wild and creates like 20 of them all over the screen, when I click one of them it hides and trigger proper "loading" function. So I'll try to decipher it and figure out where is the problem...

Comment: That Probably would have to do with the for loop everything is in, I didn't touch that (assumed it was a wanted feature) , Fixing that should fix the spawning...